# JSON Schema / Ajv - How to validate the combined lengths of an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema, ajv

Let's say that I need to validate the shipping address of an order:

```
{ "id": 1
, "recipient": "John Doe"
, "shipping_address": [ "address line 1"
                      , "address line 2"
                      , "address line 3"
                      ]
}
```

The rules for an address are:

1. Array of strings
2. At least one string (and can have as many strings as necessary)
3. The combined lengths of all strings must not exceed *X* characters (let's say 50 for the example)

I can implement 1 & 2 with the following JSON Schema:

```
{ "type": "array"
, "items": { "type": "string" }
, "minItems": 1
}
```

**Question: How do I implement condition 3 with JSON Schema / Ajv?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using [Ajv custom keywords](https://ajv.js.org/custom.html) to design the following schema:

```
{ "type": "array"
, "items": { "type": "string" }
, "minItems": 1
, "maxCombinedLength": 50
}
```

The trick is to add support for `maxCombinedLength` in Ajv:

```js
ajv.addKeyword("maxCombinedLength", {
  validate: (schema, data) => {
    return data.reduce((l, s) => l + s.length, 0) <= schema;
  }
});
```

Where:

1. `ajv` is an instance of Ajv
2. `schema` is `50`
3. `data` is the `shipping_address` array

**DEMO**

```js
const validate =
  ajv.compile({ type: 'array'
              , items: { type: 'string' }
              , minItems: 1
              , maxCombinedLength: 50
              });
              
console.log(
  validate([]));
// false (need at least one item)

console.log(
  validate([ "address line 1"
           , "address line 2"
           , "address line 3"
           ]));
// true

console.log(
  validate([ "address line 1"
           , "address line 2"
           , "address line 3"
           , "address line 4"
           , "address line 5"
           , "address line 6"
           , "address line 7"
           , "address line 8"           
           ])
, validate.errors);
// false (maxCombinedLength not satisfied!)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.12.0/ajv.min.js"></script>
<script>
const ajv = new Ajv;

ajv.addKeyword("maxCombinedLength", {
  validate: (schema, data, parent_schema) => {
    return data.reduce((l, s) => l + s.length, 0) <= schema;
  }
});

</script>
```

---

**APPENDIX: How to ignore non-string arrays?**

Obviously we can't use `maxCombinedLength` with an array of objects for example.

Thankfully Ajv allows us to get access to the parent schema:

```js
ajv.addKeyword("maxCombinedLength", {
  validate: (schema, data, parent_schema) => {
    if (parent_schema.items.type === 'string') {
      return data.reduce((l, s) => l + s.length, 0) <= schema;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

So with the following schema:

```
{ "type": "array"
, "items": { "type": "string" }
, "minItems": 1
, "maxCombinedLength": 50
}
```

The custom keyword function will receive `50` as the `schema` parameter, the array as the `data` parameter and the full schema as the `parent_schema` parameter.

The `parent_schema` parameter is used to query the type of the array. If we're not expecting strings we can nullify the `maxCombinedLength` keyword by returning `true`.